# PHP + create invoice into QuickBooks use API

Tags: php, quickbooks

Please help me, I'm integrating QuickBook API into our script and I get the message below when i run file: http://domain.com/build_20130416/dev/dev_ids_invoices.php

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method QuickBooks_IPP::application()

I'm using php script.

Comment: Linking to your file isn't the same as showing us the code.  Show us the code around where that error is.

Answer (score 1):

Please take the time to read the documentation and look at the example files in the `docs/example_app_ipp_v3/` directory for the code you downloaded. Also, *make sure you follow the [quick-start guide](http://www.consolibyte.com/docs/index.php/PHP_DevKit_for_QuickBooks_-_Intuit_Partner_Platform_Quick-Start)*. And next time, *post your code*.

If you look in the same `dev/` directory for the code you're using, you'll see a file named:

`DO_NOT_USE_THESE_FILES.txt`

With the contents:

```
DO NOT USE THE EXAMPLES IN THIS FOLDER! 

THESE ARE ALL DEVELOPMENT/TEST SCRIPTS, AND ARE NOT PRODUCTION READY!
```

You **should not be using the example script you're trying to use** just like the file says. 
It's a development testing script, and not an example that you should be using.

**Instead**, you should look at the code in the `docs` directory, which has tons of working examples. Here's a link for you to the examples on GitHub:

- https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php/tree/master/docs/example_app_ipp_v3

Specifically, here's some related to invoices:

- https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php/blob/master/docs/example_app_ipp_v3/example_invoice_add.php
- https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php/blob/master/docs/example_app_ipp_v3/example_invoice_query.php
- https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php/blob/master/docs/example_app_ipp_v3/example_invoice_w_lines_query.php
- https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php/blob/master/docs/example_app_ipp_v3/example_invoice_with_custom_fields_add.php
- https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php/blob/master/docs/example_app_ipp_v3/example_invoices_for_customer_query.php